# Solving simple trig equation

Tags: trigonometry

I tried to solve a simple trig equation.

> Solve[{Sin[x] == Cos[x], 0 <= x <=  Pi}];

The answer should be pi/4

But I get

> simplify[{{x -> -2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]}}]

Comment: Use `FullSimplify[-2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]]` to give `Pi/4`.

Comment: This is the answer. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
FindRoot[Sin[x] - Cos[x], {x, 0}]
```

Comment: `FindRoot[Sin[x] - Cos[x], {x, 0}] /.
 
 r_Real :> Pi*RootApproximant[r/Pi]`

Comment: this doesn't give the value pi/4, but an numerical approximation though. Full Simplify has worked for me.

Comment: Agreed. Depends on what you want. Like Bob's trick.Thing I've learned from this is how flexibly "equations" and "inequalities" can be combined in `Solve`